# Laravel Form PUT method not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, put

I created a form to update the role model but on clicking on the save button, it does not appear to submit to the controller method. Even the validation errors message does not appear if the name input field is invalid. Below you can find the code used for the form.

Form:

```
{!! Form::model($role, ['route' => ['roles.update', $role->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}

   @include('roles.fields')

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The fields for the form are:

```
<!-- Name Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Display Name Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   {!! Form::label('display_name', 'Display Name:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('display_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Description Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
   {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}
   {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control',   'rows' => '5']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Submit Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
   {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
   <a href="{!! route('roles.index') !!}" class="btn btn-  default">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Models\Role;

class UpdateRoleRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
     public function authorize()
     {
         return true;
     }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function rules()
     {
         return Role::$rules;
     }
}
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * Update the specified Role in storage.
 *
 * @param  int              $id
 * @param UpdateRoleRequest $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id, UpdateRoleRequest $request)
{
    $role = $this->roleRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($role)) {
        Flash::error('Role not found');

        return redirect(route('roles.index'));
    }

    $role = $this->roleRepository->update($request->all(), $id);

    Flash::success('Role updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('roles.index'));
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'roles';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'display_name',
        'description'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'display_name' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:roles'
    ];
}
```

Please help if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cant use `put` as the form method. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing) about method spoofing in laravel

```
{!! Form::model($role, ['route' => ['roles.update', $role->id], 'method' => 'post']) !!}
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

   @include('roles.fields')

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I've edited it to this and I still can't get this to work, when I click on the save button nothing happens. Let's say if I don't insert any name, it's suppose to return me a validation error message. Even the message does not show. Any reason why it's not working? Thanks

Comment: Nothing happens as in what? Does the page reload? If so that means the validation failed and never got to the Controller. To display validation errors look in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) again

Comment: Thanks for your help. I eventually managed to get it worked. It was due to the role name was unique, so everytime I was clicking on save, it was returning me an error message and in the view I didn't include the flash error message. A bit silly but thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

For those people that work with HTML and laravel 5.2:

```
<form method="post" ... > {{ method_field('PUT') }} ... </form>
```

Hope this help people.